# Нужна помощь с заполнение StringGrid

Tags: c++, stringgrid

В оконном приложении билдера нужно чтобы при нажатии на определенную ячейку StringGrid'a он заполнялся заранее заданным символом.Очень нужно.Заранее Спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Используйте событие OnSelectCell